# Encrypt database in React with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am relatively new in React with Expo. In react native, I can use Realm mobile database with encryption.

In Expo, I saw SQLite.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/

Is there a way to encrypt SQLite database in Expo? If not, what are the other alternatives for encrypted database?

Comment: look at https://forums.expo.io/t/storing-sqlite-file-securely/10377 and https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/

Comment: Thank you. I have read those before and I am already using securestore. but still need encrypted database.

Comment: if you really need an encrypted database you'll have to eject from expo and just use react native. if you're able to compromise, the best argument i've come across so far is that an unencrypted sqlite db is reasonably secure unless a) the device is jailbroken or b) you're trying to protect the db from the user themselves.

fortunately for me, demanding that my users only install my app if their devices haven't been tampered with is viable.

Answer (score 0):

Expo doesn't support Realm database :( but there is a simple solution for this. You need to encrypt first and store in database after. I am storing data like this. There is a crypto library in expo you can get information at this link.

Edit: Crypto library is for only encrypting. I said it wrong. Sorry about that. You can use Secure Store but it has size limit.

Comment: Crypto is for hashing, not encrypting/decrypting data.